# Keycloak: mapping user information from external IDP. How do I know attribute names?

Tags: keycloak, mapper, idp

I have 2 Keycloak instances:

- KC1 which is the main Keycloak for my app
- KC2 which acts as an IDP (linked to KC1 via SAML protocol)

I'm trying to retrieve users info (email, name and roles, mainly) in KC1 whenever a SSO user (from KC2) connects to my app. As far as I understand this should be done via IDP mappers.

I tried creating multiple ones with the "Attribute Importer" type with no success. The main problem is that attribute name fields are just textboxes. I don't know where to look to get the correct value I should enter here. For instance for email I tried multiple things like "email", "emailAddress", "mail", etc.. (with all possible cases, *i.e.* all uppercase, all lowercase, camelcase, etc.) but this is just guess work.

Is there a table somewhere telling what we should enter here? Or at least some way to see what is being sent in the claims (everything is very auto-magic so it's hard to know what's going on under the hood).

The documentation ( https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_mappers ) mentions that you can put the log level to debug to see the claims. Couldn't see them personally, so not sure about that.

**Edit** : found the problem for basic info (I had to create client scopes with the correct protocol, in my case SAML, and then bind it in the client on the KC2 side. Then use the SAML attribute name defined in the client scope mapper).

However, I still struggle for the roles. Do I have to create them on the KC1 side as well?

**Edit 2** : Solved. For future reference, the roles can be found in the access token (not the ID token like basic user info), but they have to be mapped in KC1 to be visible there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I still struggle for the roles. Do I have to create them on
> the KC1 side as well?

You can't simply import the roles from KC2 directly to KC1. Instead, you have to create the roles that you want in KC1, and in the appropriate IDP configuration section (of KC1) create a External Role to Role Mapper:

[image]

Where you map the role that the user has on the external IDP (*i.e.,* KC2) to the one that the user should have in the KC1. Do that for every role that you want to map.

For SAML IdP integrations you can try the same idea but using the Advance Attribute to Role mapper:

[image]